# Embed Cygwin (Git Bash) Terminal in CLion On Windows

Tags: terminal, cygwin, clion

[image: CMD embedded in CLion]
I am trying to embed the Cygwin terminal in CLion like the default Windows CMD is above.

[image: Clion Settings]
I have set the Cygwin terminal location as above in the settings.

[image: Cygwin Terminal]
But when I select the terminal it pops up a detached version as above. What I want is it embedded like the first image.

I have managed to get an embedded version of Git Bash working in PHPStorm using some flags, but these do not seem to work for Cygwin.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: What flags did you use to make Git Bash work in PHPStorm? I am tring to use Git Bash in CLion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Shell path" setting expects a path to a shell, not a terminal emulator. Please try specifying a path to bash.exe instead of mintty.exe.

Comment: This worked for me (got the terminal up and running) but it appears not to have the correct path since no commands are found (e.g. `ls`)

Answer (score 1):

If you've managed to embed the Cygwin terminal in CLion on Windows, but the commands like `ls -l`, etc. won't work, try to add the path to the directory "bin" of cygwin (e.g. C:\cygwin64\bin) to the path-variable.

https://yichaoou.github.io/tutorials/software/2016/06/28/git-bash-install-gcc

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

`X:\Git-Install-Dir\Git\bin\bash.exe` works for me.
[image]